# Does server side validation error responses have to be useful?

Tags: validation

If a user is submitting a form through my website - does the server side validation have to provide anything more than "error: invalid submission"?

If my client side validation is strong enough (and error reporting good and friendly),  and if my server side validation is strong too - does the server side error response have to transmit any useful info to the submitter?

Server side validation is for protection, not guiding the user right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server-side validation is still needed for users with Javascript disabled.
You need to decide how much support you want to give them.

You should make sure that the errors do not reveal any implementation details.

Comment: That's what I thought.  I was looking at validictory (python -json schema validation) - but the way it reports errors doesn't give enough control to limit what info gets relayed to the  (like showing password information or regexs used in its tests).  WTForms is pretty good for server side validation - but it works on forms and not a json object.